# How to make correct mod_rewrite rules in.htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make rewrite rule which rewrite this long url to a SEO friendly one.
However, my rule didn't work and the destination url become a 404 page. 
I would appreciate any helps. Thank you!

**This is an example of original URL**

http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?module=product&pId=102&id=14495&category=computer/DELL&start=0/

**This is my rewrite rule**

RewriteRule ^module/([^/]*)/pId/([^/]*)/id/([^/]*)/category/([^/]*)/start/([^/]*)$ /index.php?module=$1&pId=$2&id=$3&category=$4&start=$5 [L]

**This is transformed URL**

http://www.mydomain.com/index/module/product/pId/102/id/14495/category/computer/DELL/start/0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from a quick glance, you are matching for `/start/[^/]*$`. But your URL contains a trailing forward slash `start/0/`, which your regex excludes.

So it might be best to either allow a spare slash with `/?` or rather make the last match pattern completely imperceptive with `/start/(.*)$` allowing everything.

But anyway, just removing file extensions and trading ampersands and equal signs for forward slashes doesn't make for nicer or user-friendly URLs. The goal should be parameter consolidation for readability. Contemporary search engines don't care about GET parameters really.